# How to combine Render Layers correctly

Tags: rendering, render-layers

[image]I am having a problem with my render layers. For clear illustration, I created a plane and a box. The box is partly beneath the plane. The plane is on my first render layer and the box on the second. Now when I render, the part of the box that is below the plane is shown in black.

I know that the black part of the box is below the plane, but is there a way to cut this part from the image or even exclude it from the rendering?

I hope someone can help me.

Marijn

[image]

Comment: What do your composition nodes look like?

Comment: hi, you should perhaps share some info (or images) of relevant node setuo/render settings...

Comment: I added the node setup.

Answer (score 2):

- Option 01 - for Cube Render Layer mark Floor Render Layer as **Mask Layer**

[image]
[image]

- Option 02 - use Z-Combine node to merge them together

[image]
[image]

---

**Notes:** It is good to understand what happened in 2.8x versions ...

- **Render Layers** are almost the same concept
- **Layers** are in 2.8 represented by Collections. Now you are not selecting Collections to be rendered, but you mark collections you want to participate only indirectly - objects are not rendered directly, only indirectly by their shadow or light bounce
- **Mask Layers** are the same concept in therm of just activating collection in outliner

[image]